# XNA Framework / Monogame, creating 100 instances of object

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I am new to MonoGame and C#, and I want to initialise e.g. 100 instances of 1 object (Wheel). I have thought about using a `for-loop`, but I don't know how to go further and actually make those 100 instances.

Do I have to make an array of objects? Or can I just create e.g. `Wheel1 wheel = new Wheel();`?

This is the code I have already:

```
protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
        _wheel = new Wheel();
        _wheel.Position = new Vector2(100, 100);
        _wheel.Scale = 0.3f;
        base.Initialize();
    }
```

Comment: what you do next is entirely dependent on what you intend to do with those wheels. If you are going to use them in any way, I would suggest some form of data structure to hold them in.

Comment: @Pow-Ian Currently, I would like to use them to just instantiate and show them in the window, so what would be your advice?

Comment: you say `Do I have to make an array of objects` like it's more work than hammering out 100 lines of `Wheel`

Comment: I would suggest you clarify  your intent in your question so that you can get a better answer. The current answer is what I would suggest for storing them however unless we know what you intend to do this is a very broad and kind of unanswerable question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use a list? You may need to include this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

//Somewhere in the class
List<Wheel> myWheels = new List<Wheel>();

// In your method
var _wheel = new Wheel();

// Set your properties

myWheels.Add(_wheel);

//Then when needed, you can loop like this:
foreach(var wheel in myWheels)
{
     // do something with wheel...
}
```

I don't do XNA, but this is fairly common in C#.

Comment: When I am creating `List myWheels = new List (); ` I get an error, saying List does not exist in the current content?

Comment: Thank you, your answer doesn't raise errors anymore and I'll try to find out more about C# and XNA/MonoGame, thank you very much!